# How to write from parquet to Kafka

Tags: python, apache-spark, hadoop, apache-kafka, pyarrow

I have a `parquet` dataset. It consists of a number of `.parquet` files.

It`s schema:

- ID: INT
- NAME: STRING
- RATING: INT

I need to write it to `Kafka` using `Kafka` `python` [API](https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/) or any other way (possibly using `python` tools). Both `HDFS` `namenode` and `Kafka` are remote machines. Let's set their hostnames to `namenode` and `Kafka`.

I found a couple of ways to do it searching the solution:

- `pyarrow` - a tool for working with datasets. Is supports reading from `HDFS` and it is possible to read from parquet and then iterating through this, write data to `Kafka` in any needed format. This solution seems too "hand made" for this task.
- Read `parquet` using any `Spark` API (for example, `Spark.SQL`). And then write to `Kafka` somehow. This method seems to be too "hand made" as well.

I am also not sure about format of data inside `Kafka`. I guess it should be something like `.json`. The final goal is to be able to read data from `Kafka` `topic` using `Spark` `structured-streaming` API to do some educational tasks with dataset.

What is the best way to do what I want (write multiple `.parquet` files with the same schema to `Kafka` with an ability to set up format inside `Kafka`)?

Comment: The data format in Kafka is bytes. There's no format in the broker. The Spark docs explicitly say you write bytes or utf8 strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have 2 answers for your question :

- If you're sure your parquet files will always respect the same schema you specified or you'll handle that after consuming Kafka's data, Using Spark to read and send parquet to Kafka may be over-engineering. Spark is designed to apply computations over your data before writing it somewhere. In this case, you can simply use the Kafka Python API along with PyArrow.

```py
    import pyarrow.parquet as pq

    #You can iterate over the files you have in the directory and send your records one by one

    def send_parquet_records(parquet_file):
        table = pq.read_table(parquet_file)
        schema = table.schema
        records = table.to_pandas()
    
        for _, record in records.iterrows():
            message = record.to_json()
            producer.send('your_topic_name', value=message.encode(), key=None)
```

- If you're not sure your data will always respect schema and you need to be sure that all lines matches the schema, I'd suggest you to use Spark to control existance and types of your columns before writing data in Kafka.

Comment: Question seems to want to write Parquet to kafka, not json